# Compiling a standalone figure with input from an external file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I am trying to compile the following code with data.txt as CSV values. The point is that it works perfectly inside a text, but trying to do so in a standalone mode causes TexStudio to halt. Also the cmd breaks with the output shown after the code

```
  \documentclass{standalone}
 % The following inclusions are required for the LaTeX drawing environment Tikz
 \usepackage{tikz} 
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

 \usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, external}
 \tikzexternalize

 \usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors]{circuitikz}

 \begin{document}

     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \begin{axis}
          \addplot+[mark = none, solid, black] table [x=theta, y=h0, col sep=comma] {RP_16_50.txt};
         \addlegendentry{$f_0$};
          \addplot+[mark = none, dotted, black] table [x=theta, y=h1, col sep=comma] {RP_16_50.txt};
          \addlegendentry{$f_0 + f_B$};
          \addplot+[mark = none, dashed, black] table [x=theta, y=h_1, col sep=comma] {RP_16_50.txt};
\addlegendentry{$f_0 - f_B$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the CMD output is as follows:

```
 Output written on TRY_FIELD.pdf (1 page, 21585 bytes).SyncTeX: Can't rename TRY_FIELD.synctex.gz(busy) to TRY_FIELD.synctex.gz
 Transcript written on TRY_FIELD.log.
```

What is the wrong thing in here? Cheers,

Comment: did you have a previous run that did not shut down correctly, you have a process holding the synctex file open by the look of it

Comment: Doesn't `pgfplots` have a specialised externalisation library?

Comment: Uh, why would you want to externalize standalone?  All externalize does is run standalone in another process.